# Execute and create one python script from another

Tags: python

Suppose, I have a python script `test1.py` , executing of `test1.py` will create a copy of that file, let's say `test2.py` . Now, I want to run `test1.py` in such a way that first it will create `test2.py` and then will execute `test2.py` .

This is my `test1.py` python script looks like,

```
import io
import shutil
import os

shutil.copy2('test1.py', 'test2.py')
os.system("test2.py")
```

But out is saying `test2.py: not found`

Comment: Try using the complete path during the script creation and execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run python with `test2.py` as it's first argument.

```
os.system("python test2.py")
```

If you say what's your goal of this action. We can help you better.